# How to install aparapi

Tags: java, opencl, aparapi

I have been looking to a way to develop openCL in Java. I found aparapi interesting as it focusses on parallelization but creates openCL code as well. As I understand it the code will run with or without a GPU but still run parallized. My trouble is: where can I find documentation on how to install what? The [AMD site](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/opencl-zone/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/) was often pointed at, but it contains no information about aparapi, I wondered as well whether their code will work on Nvidia cards. The links to Google code is obsolete and the Github site is neither very helpful. A pointer to some more documentation is very much appreciated.

As an aside: I noticed in Github that the aparapi pulse is not overwhelming. Is it wise to start with aparapi? I thought I had better stay from openCL itself because it seemed too low level to me. But maybe somebody can argument how I could make a better founded decision ([LWJGL](https://www.lwjgl.org/)?).

Comment: Did you ever resolve this ticket? I provided an answer below but never heard back.

Answer (score 5):

**Note: I'm the current lead of the Aparapi project.** If you use the version of Aparapi in maven central, no need to install anything. Assuming you have any implementation of OpenCL installed then everything is installed that needs to be. Aparapi pulls in dependencies through maven and even the dll/so file for your platform and loads it automatically.

Full instructions found here: http://aparapi.com/introduction/getting-started.html

The actively maintained project for aparapi can be found on github here: https://github.com/Syncleus/Aparapi

Or some information and documentation on the website here: http://aparapi.com

Answer (score 1):

## Aparapi is great

as you can write code on Java and run it on the GPU. It also has great features for buffer transfer between memory - GPU memory.
We developed a cluster-computing bruteforce-engine with GPU acceleration: http://hgs-studios.com/#/projects/bruteforce

To install it, make sure you update your graphics card drivers.
You can download the OpenCL drivers from here: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-drivers

If you have a recent version of Nvidia drivers and DirectX installed, you do not need to do anything.
Just make sure you have the native libraries of your OS linked via
`java "-Djava.library.path=lib\aparapi_native" -jar myjar.jar` when running.

Check out these guides to get started with coding:

https://github.com/aparapi/aparapi/blob/master/doc/UsersGuide.md

https://github.com/aparapi/aparapi/blob/master/doc/JavaKernelGuidelines.md

https://github.com/aparapi/aparapi/blob/master/doc/AparapiPatterns.md

Comment: Those links are to the obsolete project. The new project has similar updated documentation at http://aparapi.com